# Responsive Ads for AMP Sites (width only)

Tags: amp-html

Is there any solution to add a responsive Adsense to AMP?
Like 100px height (for calculate the layout) and 100% width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me. It take a max high eq 100px and width: 100%

```
<amp-ad   
    width="320" height="100"  
    media="(max-height: 100px)"  
    layout="responsive"  
    type="adsense"  
    class="adsbygoogle ads_mystyle"  
    data-ad-client="xxx"  
    data-ad-slot="xxx">  
</amp-ad>
```

Comment: How to set  googletag.pubads().set("document_language", "en");
for the amp-ads, any idea?

Comment: @SaurabhSashank Ask this as a separate question. I'll be able to help.

Comment: @Amrinder Dahul we need your help here.. can you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [blog](https://www.thedev.blog/3054/how-to-make-amp-adsense-ads-responsive-accelerated-mobile-pages/), AMP HTML for Adsense can be made responsive with CSS since AMP is Asynchronous. As you are going to use the asynchronous Adcodes, you need to include this script in the head section of your HTML.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Here is the sample code:

```
<style>
.headerad { width: 100%; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 320px) { .headerad { width: 320px; height: 100px; } }
</style>
<amp-ad class="headerad"
 type="adsense"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"
 data-ad-slot="YYYY">
</amp-ad>
```

If you want to [Customize Google Adsense Async Responsive ADS Size](https://www.thedev.blog/3054/how-to-make-amp-adsense-ads-responsive-accelerated-mobile-pages/), you need first to to generate an Adsense `adunit`.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- ADUnit -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
 data-ad-slot="yyyyyy"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

**Header Ad:**

```
<style>
.headerad { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 468px) { .headerad { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 728px) { .headerad { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
<!-- Header Ad -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle headerad"
 style="display:inline-block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
 data-ad-slot="yyyy"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No that's not work. For AMP you must enter a size like:   
<amp-ad width=300 height=200  
    type="adsense"  
    data-ad-client="xxx"  
    data-ad-slot="xxx">  
</amp-ad>
You can't modify this with css.

Answer (score 2):

AMP Project forbidden style and max-height there are 2 range  responsive amp ads code.

#### 1. For header or page in or post in, width is not required

**Width :** flexible responsive 'the width of the area'.

**Height :** max 400 & flexible. (problem sidebar wrapper - problem footer problems mobile view)

```
<amp-ad
    layout="fixed-height"   
    height="400"  
    type="adsense" 
    data-ad-format='auto'
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-1234567898xx"  
    data-ad-slot="9876xx"
></amp-ad>
```

#### 2. With width and height

For everywhere (but sometimes it's not responsive)

```
<amp-ad
    layout="responsive"   
    height="336"
    width="280"  
    type="adsense" 
    data-ad-format='auto'
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-12345678xx"  
    data-ad-slot="9876xx"
></amp-ad>
```

Comment: Please edit that answer, the format is bad.  When you edit your answer, look at the hints for editing.  Right now you have text mixed with code.  Lastly question yourself if this answer brings anything new to the other answers already present.